# Exception passing a header value to request library Create Session

Tags: python, json, robotframework

I have the following in  my Robotframework keyword:

```
${headers}=  Set Variable  {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
Create Session  sample  ${url}  headers=${headers}  disable_warnings=1
```

But I'm getting the following error in `Create session`.

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

This is not working only for this `header`.  I have tried using

```
{"Content-Type": "application${/}json"}
```

which didnt help.

Answer (score 3):

What you obviously tried to do is to create a dictionary (to pass as a headers argument), but that's not the way to accomplish this in Robotframework.
The keyword `Set Variable` creates a var of type `string` if you pass an argument that is string-like - it does not deduct that you tried to create a dictionary just by the presence of the curly brackets.

This is how you can create a real dictionary (a `dict` (sub)type in python):

```
${headers}=    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=application/json
```

When you pass this variable to `Create Session` it now will be a proper `dict`, and the keyword shouldn't fail because of that.

```
Create Session    sample    ${url}    headers=${headers}    disable_warnings=1
```